# st_intersection LINESTRING with borders of POLYGONs while preserving the order of points in r / sf

Tags: r, gis, spatial, r-sf

I need to intersect a `LINESTRING` with the borders `POLYGON` feature, while preserving the order of the resulting `POINT` features. The background is that I need to figure out the border crossings car took for entering/leaving a specific country, but the order of the border crossings matters.

I have implemented the following approach:

```
# setup test data
  poly <- 
    list(matrix(c(0,0,10,0,10,10,0,10,0,0),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)) %>% 
    sf::st_polygon() %>% 
    sf::st_sfc() %>% 
    sf::st_sf()

  line1 <- matrix(c(-1, 10, 5, -1),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) %>% 
    sf::st_linestring() %>% 
    sf::st_sfc() %>% 
    sf::st_sf()

  # reverse of line 1
  line2 <- matrix(c(5, -1, -1, 10), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) %>% 
    sf::st_linestring() %>% 
    sf::st_sfc() %>% 
    sf::st_sf()

  # preview
  leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
    leaflet::addPolygons(data = poly) %>% 
    leaflet::addPolylines(data = line1) %>%
    leaflet::addPolylines(data = line2) %>% 
    leaflet::addTiles()


# do the intersection
  # cast to multilinestring because I just need the border crossing points
  ml <- sf::st_cast(poly, "MULTILINESTRING") 
  sf::st_intersection(ml, line1)
  sf::st_intersection(ml, line2)
```

However, this approach loses the order of the border crossings. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: I would just add a column indicating a linestrings direction. Then you can order your points accordingly.

Comment: its just a single linestring that can have multiple intersections with country borders, so that would not work (if i understood your comment correctly)

Comment: I would segmentize the line strings, add a column indicating direction, spatial join to the intersection points, and sort points by direction indicator.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I played around with `st_segmentize()`, but it only adds extra vertices to a linestring (without creating new rows in the `sf` object). I googled around a bit and found a different solution to my problem. I'll leave the question open for a while in case someone comes up with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that involves `rgeos::gProject()`. This function calculates distances between points along a line, and I can use it to derive a sort order for my points:

```
# do the intersection
ml <- sf::st_cast(poly, "MULTILINESTRING") 

points1 <- sf::st_intersection(ml, line1) %>% 
  sf::st_cast("POINT")

points2 <- sf::st_intersection(ml, line2) %>% 
  sf::st_cast("POINT")

# Calculate sort order for the points
points1$order <- rgeos::gProject(sf::as_Spatial(line1), sf::as_Spatial(points1))
points2$order <- rgeos::gProject(sf::as_Spatial(line2), sf::as_Spatial(points2))
```